# How to check if sequence cycles or repeats

Tags: python, collatz

I have a program that generates numbers of the 3n + 1 problem. The program takes a value of n and iterates until n becomes 1.

```
n = 49

number = n
current_iter = 0 
computed_nums = [n] 
iterations = [0]
while n != 1:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = (n / 2)
    else:
        n = ((n * 3) + 1)
    current_iter += 1
    computed_nums.append(n)
    iterations.append(current_iter)

print("Computed numbers: " + str(computed_nums))
print("Iterations required: " + str(current_iter))
```

How can I check if the sequence ever cycles or repeats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to keep track of which numbers you've already visited and check if `n` is one of them.

```
n = 49

computed_nums = {}
while n not in computed_nums:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        res = n // 2
    else:
        res = n*3 + 1
    computed_nums[n] = res
    n = res  # For next loop

print(list(computed_nums))
print("Iterations:", len(computed_nums)-1)
```

Output:

```
[49, 148, 74, 37, 112, 56, 28, 14, 7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
Iterations: 24
```

Here I'm using a dict, which preserves insertion order as of Python 3.7.

Note: The Collatz conjecture has been tested up to 2<sup>68</sup>, so checking if `n == 1` is enough in practice.

Comment: I do have to; it is for an assignment.

Comment: @Dila Sorry, I did include how to do it, but maybe it wasn't clear. I edited to clarify.

Comment: So, it never cycles or repeats then? Also, I have to keep track of iterations for each computed num to plot computed num vs iterations.

Comment: @Dila As far as we know, it only cycles at 4,2,1. Have you not read about the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)?